# How to kill Powershell instance if launched by system command in c++?

Tags: c++, powershell

I am invoking Powershell script through System command in cpp from one process. Powershell script is invoking correctly from system command but after script execution Powershell process is not ending.

Is there any way to kill powershell process if process is launched by system command in cpp?

```
int rc = system(("powershell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned "      + filePath + " > " + filePathOut).c_str());
```

When this code execute it launched the powershell but powershell 
process does not kill after code execution.

Comment: Could not reproduce it with a simple script; the PowerShell process exits as expected. Does the issue still occur when you call a simple script like "echo 'bla bla'" ?

Comment: Actually I have a process say "abc" and in that process this system command runs to execute powershell script. Yeah It got hang for simple script also.

While I try this code from visual studio as stand alone, I don't see any error but while launch this code my application process this issue come.